# Get request return error code 405 - method not allowed

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlsession

I've wrote a function for GET request from rest and it says that i have method not allowed - code 405 which is werid and i can not find solution for that.

I am doing GET via current token which was assigned to the user after logged in.

Could someone have a look on the code and tell me what might be wrong ?

```
func getRequest() -> Void {

    let json: [String: Any] = ["token": SessionMenager.Instance.token]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: MY_URL)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.setValue("application/json;charest=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("GET : code -  \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }

        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
        } else{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does your **server** allows GET with the url you're trying?

Comment: @user28434 Yeah, it does!

Comment: can you add request via `curl` result(and request itself) to the question? With masking all private info, ofc.

Comment: the code looks fine and if u say the server allows GET it must be something wrong with your headers. Please try what @user28434 proposed

Comment: @user28434 could you show an example how can i do this ?

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown, here's [cheatsheet](https://www.cheatography.com/ankushagarwal11/cheat-sheets/curl-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: @user28434 -X<GET> in console ?

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown, ok [examples](http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/curl-tutorial-examples-usage/) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxUVU0b95Oc)

Comment: @user28434 meanwhile i've got 403 code